How can I make a child server component dynamic
Consider the following code
// layout.tsx

export default function Layout({children}: any) {
  return <div>
      {children}
  </div>
}

// page.tsx

export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";

const DynamicChild = dynamic(() => import("@/DynamicChild"), {
    ssr: true,
})

export default function Page({children}: any) {
  return <div>
      <DynamicChild />  
  </div>
}

// DynamicChild.tsx



export default function DynamicChild() {
  return <div>
      {process.env.imporantEnvVar ? "cat": "dog"}  
  </div>
}

When a page is marked as export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";, the dynamic rendering of DynamicChild works. But not all the pages are in a good position to add "force-dynamic", and they should be statically rendered as much as possible at build time besides the <DynamicChild>.
How to achieve this while maintaining all the components server side rendered?

You don't have to export const dynamic = "force-dynmaic" to dynamically render a page, Next.js will figure it out automatically when you use dynamic data such as cookies, headers, searchParams, fetch with revalidate: 0 or cache: "no-store" and so on.
If you don't use any of these APIs and want to force dynamic rendering you can call unstable_noStore at any component in the tree:
// dynamic-component.tsx

import { unstable_noStore as noStore } from 'next/cache';

export default function DynamicChild() {
 
  noStore();

  return <div>
      {process.env.imporantEnvVar ? "cat": "dog"}  
  </div>
}

This way, when noStore is executed, Next.js will mark the page that it's used in as dynamic rendering or the component if you're using PPR.


they should be statically rendered as much as possible at build time besides the .

It seems like you're trying to make the page renders statically at the build time except the dynamic component. If so, you should enable Partial Pre-render aka PPR

For You Information:

dynamic() has nothing to do with Server Components

const DynamicChild = dynamic(() => import("@/DynamicChild"), {
    ssr: true,
})

doesn't do anything at Server Components. It has effects only when you import a Client Component from a Client Component. It has nothing to do with Server Components.

Environment Variables are injected in the output chunk at the build time, changing an environment variable requires re-building. I'm mentioning this just in case you think that changing process.env.imporantEnvVar will affect the output.


Hi Ahmed, I would like to clarify on “Environment Variables are injected in the output chunk at the build time, ”, so if I use PPR for a dynamic child component following the suggestion above, would it still use the value at build time?

It doesn't matter whether using PPR or not. Next.js will not react to changes in .env files after the build process. Runtime values require different approaches other than environment variables. https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables

"With the App Router, we can safely read environment variables on the server during dynamic rendering. " i can observe this behavior, so what does your "Environment Variables are injected in the output chunk at the build time, changing an environment variable requires re-building" refer to?

Let's say you set the value of imporantEnvVar=cat then next build. If you went to .env file and changed the value to dog, It won't change to dog until you run next build again.

My observation is that as long as I restart the app with next start , it will pick up the new value of dog. It does not require rebuild. Otherwise what the doc says we can safely read environment variables on the server during dynamic rendering.  makes no sense. Not sure why you believe the value has to be baked with build.

Maybe what you refer to only applys to the NEXT_PUBLIC_* client-facing env vars?

I tried to reproduce with TEST and NEXT_PUBLIC_TEST. Both has the same behavior. Editing .env.local won't apply until rebuilding

I may be wrong that environment variables are always injected to the build output all the time. The documentation mentions this behavior for client variables only. But it still isn't updated without rebuilding

Thanks for trying it out. I am on Next.js 14.1.3. First I run next build, then next start, see the env var being rendered with one value. Kill the nextjs process, modify the env var in the .env (.env.local should work too) to a different value. Re-launch with next start again without rebuidling. I can see the value changed.
Maybe what's different in your use case is that your page.tsx doesn't have either "force-dynamic" nor unstable_noStore , so it is not dynamic and just static. In such cases, I do observe that it can only take values from build time.

It does require that the "force-dynamic" or unstable_noStore being used in the root page.tsx file not any of its decedent components. Otherwise the whole route will still be marked static.
